# Exception occurred at =: unknown error: call function result missing 'value' using Selenium Python and ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am a new software developer, and have been asked to edit some scripting test written with Cucumber, but the code is throwing an exception that my team does not recognize.

```
Exception occurred at =: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.134)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19042 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

I am not sure what I am allowed to share but this s the exception that is being thrown. I heard that it could have something to do with the Chrome Driver, but I am not sure how possible it is to update them (I would need to submit a ticket and get the update approved). Has anyone experienced this issue before, and have you had luck finding a solution?

A quick side note. The issue is only happening with my system. The other person working on this with me is not experiencing any issues.

Comment: This error is not related to cucumber. Hence I made a bit of update

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Exception occurred at =: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.134)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19042 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chrome=103.0*
- But you are using *chromedriver=2.29*

which is **old** and **ancient**.

So there is a clear mismatch between *chrome=103.0* and the *chromedriver=2.29*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [***Version 4.3.0***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v103.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=103.0.5060.53/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=103.0* (as per [chromedriver=103.0.5060.53 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/103.0.5060.53/notes.txt)).